# Possible to pass data from a view controller to its delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a table view controller that I would like to be able to pass data to its delegate whenever a cell is selected. Is this possible?

The delegate view controller is essentially a settings page and when you submit the selected settings it passes an object to the TableViewController to update the cell's text.

I would like to be able to pass the indexPath.row and indexPath.section of the selected table cell to the delegate view so that it can be used and stored in the object that gets passed back to the table view controller.

*I am not using segues

Comment: please add code of what you tried!

Comment: "Is this possible?" Yes, obviously it is. Just follow the standard protocol-delegate pattern. See "Passing Data Back" discussion in the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5210535/1271826